# ¿Cómo trabajar con JSON en Java?

Tags: java, json, api

Tengo la siguiente petición [URL](https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/TOP/31,80/forecast), esta me devuelve un JSON.

Realizo la petición en Java de la siguiente manera:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String uri = "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/TOP/31,80/forecast";

    OkHttpClient cliente = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(uri).build();

    try {
      Response response = cliente.newCall(request).execute();
      System.out.println("Codigo de respuesta: " + response.code());
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        String data = response.body().string();
        System.out.println(data);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Obtengo el JSON completo en String. Pero necesito este array de la respuesta:

```
"periods": [
{
"number": 1,
"name": "Tonight",
"startTime": "2021-10-09T20:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-10T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 58,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "W",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/ovc?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Cloudy",
"detailedForecast": "Cloudy, with a low around 58. West wind 5 to 10 mph."
},
{
"number": 2,
"name": "Sunday",
"startTime": "2021-10-10T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-10T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 71,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 15 mph",
"windDirection": "NW",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/rain_showers,20/rain_showers,40?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Chance Rain Showers",
"detailedForecast": "A chance of rain showers after 7am. Cloudy, with a high near 71. Northwest wind 5 to 15 mph. Chance of precipitation is 40%."
},
{
"number": 3,
"name": "Sunday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-10T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-11T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 50,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 mph",
"windDirection": "W",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/rain_showers,40?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Chance Rain Showers",
"detailedForecast": "A chance of rain showers. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 50. West wind around 5 mph. Chance of precipitation is 40%."
},
{
"number": 4,
"name": "Columbus Day",
"startTime": "2021-10-11T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-11T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 71,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "NW",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/rain_showers,20/sct?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Slight Chance Rain Showers then Mostly Sunny",
"detailedForecast": "A slight chance of rain showers before 7am. Mostly sunny, with a high near 71. Northwest wind 5 to 10 mph. Chance of precipitation is 20%."
},
{
"number": 5,
"name": "Monday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-11T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-12T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 47,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 mph",
"windDirection": "S",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Mostly Clear",
"detailedForecast": "Mostly clear, with a low around 47. South wind around 5 mph."
},
{
"number": 6,
"name": "Tuesday",
"startTime": "2021-10-12T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-12T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 74,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 15 mph",
"windDirection": "SE",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Sunny",
"detailedForecast": "Sunny, with a high near 74. Southeast wind 5 to 15 mph, with gusts as high as 25 mph."
},
{
"number": 7,
"name": "Tuesday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-12T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-13T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 57,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "15 mph",
"windDirection": "SE",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/tsra_sct,30/tsra_sct,80?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Chance Showers And Thunderstorms",
"detailedForecast": "A chance of showers and thunderstorms between 7pm and 1am, then showers and thunderstorms. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 57. Southeast wind around 15 mph, with gusts as high as 30 mph. Chance of precipitation is 80%."
},
{
"number": 8,
"name": "Wednesday",
"startTime": "2021-10-13T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-13T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 69,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "15 to 20 mph",
"windDirection": "SW",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra_hi,80/tsra_hi,50?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Showers And Thunderstorms",
"detailedForecast": "Showers and thunderstorms before 1pm. Mostly sunny, with a high near 69. Southwest wind 15 to 20 mph, with gusts as high as 30 mph. Chance of precipitation is 80%."
},
{
"number": 9,
"name": "Wednesday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-13T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-14T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 43,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 15 mph",
"windDirection": "W",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Mostly Clear",
"detailedForecast": "Mostly clear, with a low around 43. West wind 5 to 15 mph, with gusts as high as 25 mph."
},
{
"number": 10,
"name": "Thursday",
"startTime": "2021-10-14T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-14T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 65,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "N",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Sunny",
"detailedForecast": "Sunny, with a high near 65."
},
{
"number": 11,
"name": "Thursday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-14T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-15T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 44,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "N",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/sct?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Partly Cloudy",
"detailedForecast": "Partly cloudy, with a low around 44."
},
{
"number": 12,
"name": "Friday",
"startTime": "2021-10-15T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-15T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 59,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "10 to 15 mph",
"windDirection": "N",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Mostly Sunny",
"detailedForecast": "Mostly sunny, with a high near 59."
},
{
"number": 13,
"name": "Friday Night",
"startTime": "2021-10-15T18:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-16T06:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": false,
"temperature": 40,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "NW",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Mostly Clear",
"detailedForecast": "Mostly clear, with a low around 40."
},
{
"number": 14,
"name": "Saturday",
"startTime": "2021-10-16T06:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2021-10-16T18:00:00-05:00",
"isDaytime": true,
"temperature": 62,
"temperatureUnit": "F",
"temperatureTrend": null,
"windSpeed": "5 to 10 mph",
"windDirection": "NW",
"icon": "https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/few?size=medium",
"shortForecast": "Sunny",
"detailedForecast": "Sunny, with a high near 62."
}
]
```

Necesito rescatar ese array de la respuesta convertirlo en un Objeto List<> para recorrer y aplicar filtros según las fechas. Primera vez que me toca trabajar en Java con HTTP solicitudes y JSON. No sé que librerías son buenas o de que manera filtrar el JSON para obtener solo ciertos parametros y no todo el objeto.

Comment: La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos.

Estas preguntas tienden a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado la solución con ayuda de la librería de Google GSON.

Primero necesite crear una clase en Java con las propiedades que contendrá el JSON que recibiré de la petición.

En este caso tengo dos clases, una que es el objeto completo el cual llamé Forecast.java que contendrá las propiedades que devuelve el request a la API. Utilizando la librería de Google puedo declarar que será de tipo JsonArray o JsonObject.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class Forecast {

    JsonArray context;
    String type;
    JsonObject geometry;
    JsonObject properties;

    public JsonArray getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public final void setContext(JsonArray context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public final void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public JsonObject getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public final void setGeometry(JsonObject geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }

    public JsonObject getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public final void setProperties(JsonObject properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Forecast() {
        setContext(new JsonArray());
        setType("");
        setGeometry(new JsonObject());
        setProperties(new JsonObject());
    }

    public Forecast(JsonArray context, String type, JsonObject geometry, JsonObject properties) {
        setContext(context);
        setType(type);
        setGeometry(geometry);
        setProperties(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Forecast{context=").append(getContext());
        sb.append(", type=").append(getType());
        sb.append(", geometry=").append(getGeometry());
        sb.append(", properties=").append(getProperties());
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Y la clase Period, la cual contendrá todos los objetos del array periods que contiene el JSON, que es en realidad el que necesito para obtener la predicción de los próximos 3 días.

```
public final class Period {

    private int number;
    private String name;
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;
    private boolean isDayTime;
    private int temperature;
    private String temperatureUnit;
    private String temperatureTrend;
    private String windSpeed;
    private String windDirection;
    private String icon;
    private String shortForecast;
    private String detailedForecast;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Date startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Date endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public boolean isIsDayTime() {
        return isDayTime;
    }

    public void setIsDayTime(boolean isDayTime) {
        this.isDayTime = isDayTime;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getTemperatureUnit() {
        return temperatureUnit;
    }

    public void setTemperatureUnit(String temperatureUnit) {
        this.temperatureUnit = temperatureUnit;
    }

    public String getTemperatureTrend() {
        return temperatureTrend;
    }

    public void setTemperatureTrend(String temperatureTrend) {
        this.temperatureTrend = temperatureTrend;
    }

    public String getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(String windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public String getWindDirection() {
        return windDirection;
    }

    public void setWindDirection(String windDirection) {
        this.windDirection = windDirection;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getShortForecast() {
        return shortForecast;
    }

    public void setShortForecast(String shortForecast) {
        this.shortForecast = shortForecast;
    }

    public String getDetailedForecast() {
        return detailedForecast;
    }

    public void setDetailedForecast(String detailedForecast) {
        this.detailedForecast = detailedForecast;
    }

    public Period() {
        this.number = 0;
        this.name = "";
        this.startTime = new Date();
        this.endTime = new Date();
        this.isDayTime = true;
        this.temperature = 58;
        this.temperatureUnit = "F";
        this.temperatureTrend = null;
        this.windSpeed = "";
        this.windDirection = "NW";
        this.icon = "";
        this.shortForecast = "";
        this.detailedForecast = "";
    }

    public Period(int number, String name, Date startTime, Date endTime, boolean isDayTime, int temperature, String temperatureUnit, String temperatureTrend, String windSpeed, String windDirection, String icon, String shortForecast, String detailedForecast) {
        setNumber(number);
        setName(name);
        setStartTime(startTime);
        setEndTime(endTime);
        setIsDayTime(isDayTime);
        setTemperature(temperature);
        setTemperatureUnit(temperatureUnit);
        setTemperatureTrend(temperatureTrend);
        setWindSpeed(windSpeed);
        setWindDirection(windDirection);
        setIcon(icon);
        setShortForecast(shortForecast);
        setDetailedForecast(detailedForecast);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Period{number=").append(getNumber());
        sb.append(", name=").append(getName());
        sb.append(", startTime=").append(getStartTime());
        sb.append(", endTime=").append(getEndTime());
        sb.append(", isDayTime=").append(isIsDayTime());
        sb.append(", temperature=").append(getTemperature());
        sb.append(", temperatureUnit=").append(getTemperatureUnit());
        sb.append(", temperatureTrend=").append(getTemperatureTrend());
        sb.append(", windSpeed=").append(getWindSpeed());
        sb.append(", windDirection=").append(getWindDirection());
        sb.append(", icon=").append(getIcon());
        sb.append(", shortForecast=").append(getShortForecast());
        sb.append(", detailedForecast=").append(getDetailedForecast());
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Una vez que tenemos los modelos listos para recibir los datos, realize la solicitud mediante la siguiente función que recibe los grados de longitud y latitud de la locación.

```
public static void peticionHttpGet(int longitud, int latitud) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/TOP/" + longitud + "," + latitud + "/forecast");
        HttpURLConnection conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
        try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream()))) {
            String linea;
            while ((linea = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                resultado.append(linea);
            }
        }
        Gson data = new Gson();
        Forecast f = data.fromJson(resultado.toString(), Forecast.class);
        int cont = 0;
        Date fechaActual = new Date();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : f.getProperties().getAsJsonArray("periods")) {
            Period p = data.fromJson(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject(), Period.class);
            if (p.isIsDayTime()) {
                if (Functions.calcularProximosDias(p.getStartTime(), fechaActual)) {
                    System.out.println("La temperatura para el día "
                            + p.getStartTime()
                            + " será de "
                            + Functions.parseToCelsius(p.getTemperature())
                            + " ° Celsius");
                    fechaActual = p.getStartTime();
                    cont++;
                    if (cont == 3) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Este método ejecuta toda la lógica que requiere la función y muestra en consola el pronóstico para los proximos 3 días. Lo que quiero destacar de esta función, es la librería GSON, que me permite crear un objeto de clase mediante un JSON y así poder acceder a todas sus propiedades.

```
Gson data = new Gson();
Forecast f = data.fromJson(resultado.toString(), Forecast.class);
```

Estás simples lineas generan una clase GSON que contiene las funciones que permiten trabajar con objetos json. Mediante el método `from.Json()` este método recibe un objeto JSON, en este caso recibe el resultado de la solicitud HTTP y como segundo argumento, la clase con el tipo. Esto ya crea una instancia del objeto como una clase y podemos acceder a las propiedades con los accesadores propios de la clase. (Esto es increíblemente fácil y efectivo).

Luego como mencione yo necesitaba acceder a la propiedad con clave `"periods"` del objeto JSON (un array con los pronosticos); Entonces para esto, lo único que debo hacer es utilizar la siguiente línea:

```
f.getProperties().getAsJsonArray("periods")
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es el array con los pronosticos de los proximos días. Ya simplemente queda aplicar la lógica necesaria.

Me sorprendió la facilidad de esta librería desarrollada por Google, desde hoy se convierte en mi librería favorita en cuanto a objetos JSON. Me parece muy facil trabajar, sobre todo que siempre he trabajado con patrones de arquitectura MVC y REST orientada a objetos.

Answer (score -1):

Justo este tema a mi se me complico un poco, el manejo de objetos JSON, ¿que te recomiedo? Utilizar la Api Gson de Java ya que es muy
sencilla y fácil de implementar.

Te dejo un post sobre el Asunto.https://jarroba.com/gson-json-java-ejemplos/

Comment: Muchas gracias la revisaré de inmediato!  Esto en JavaScript es muy simple pero en Java se complica un poco, pero estoy seguro que existe la manera!

Comment: Ruslan López Coincido en eso con vos, el tema es que es una guía y ejemplificación propia del que realizó la página y blog, los derechos son reservados. También Juan Fernando Huenchun preguntó sobre librerías y usos con json en Java, por eso es que le recomendé ese material, saludos